# In general, ++ is the same thing as +1. Why ++ != +1 on this code?

Tags: php

I used foreach, &, ++, +1.

In general, ++ is the same thing as +1.
but ++ != +1 on this code`(php7.3.4)`, why?

```php
$data1 = $data2 = [
    ['id' => 0],
    ['id' => 1],
    ['id' => 2],
];
foreach ($data1 as $key => &$val) {
    $val['id'] = $val['id']++;
}
foreach ($data2 as $key => &$val) {
    $val['id'] = $val['id']+1;
}

var_dump($data1 == $data2); // false. why?
```

thank [Nigel Ren](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1213708/nigel-ren)

I change this code

```php
foreach ($data1 as $key => &$val) {
    // $val['id'] = $val['id']++;
    $val['id']++;
}
```

the result is `true`.
but i don't know why `$val['id'] = $val['id']++` != `$val['id']++`?

Comment: I know your mean. But it's not my want. I uesd ++ and +1.

Comment: Try using `$val['id']++;` instead of the first assignment.

Comment: Yes, I uesd `$val['id']++` and the value is true. @Nigel Ren .

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is a basic difference between $i++ and ++$i.

### pre-increment

++$i is Pre-increment, Increments $i by one, then returns $i

### post-increment

$i++ is Post-increment, Returns $i, then increments $i by one

### Addition

$i += 1 is Addition, adds 1, then return $i

Please have a look: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php

In your case use

```
$val['id']++;
```

instead of

```
$val['id'] = $val['id']++;
```

Hope, it helps.

Comment: Yes, the result is `true`, but i don't know why `$val['id'] = $val['id']++` != `$val['id']++`?

Comment: This is because value of $val['id'] is assigned in the variable first, then incremented. here is one extra operations, but $val['id']++ is only one operation.

Comment: I know this question is `$x = $x++` != `$x++` now, thank you very much!

Comment: Doesn't `val` get incremented after the assignment?

Comment: The document say `Returns $a, then increments $a by one.`. So `$x = $x++` == `$x = $x`.

Comment: `$x` is assigned `$x`, then `$x` is incremented by 1.@nyx

Comment: yes, you are right. [JMP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4361999/jmp)